# How does IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath get set?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.2

In my Azure Service Fabric Web API project, I am able to add my appsettings.json files to my config using this code in my `Api.cs` class:

```
    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
    {
        return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
        {
            new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
                new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
                {
                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                    return new WebHostBuilder()
                                .UseKestrel()
                                .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
                                {
                                        var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;
                                        config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                                            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                                })
                                .ConfigureServices((hostingContext, services) => services
                                .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                                .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(hostingContext.Configuration))
                                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                                .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                                .UseUrls(url)
                                .Build();
                }))
        };
    }
```

The `env.ContentRootPath` contains this value:

```
C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\Abc.IntegrationType_App197\Abc.Integration.ApiPkg.Code.1.0.0
```

In this folder I can see the appsettings.json files.

However, in my Azure Service Fabric Stateless Service project, I have this code in my `Service.cs` class:

```
    protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
            {
                var env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

                var appName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
                var parentFolderPath = Directory.GetParent(env.ContentRootPath).FullName;
                var packageCodeFolderPath = Path.Combine(parentFolderPath, appName + "Pkg.Code.1.0.0");

                config.SetBasePath(packageCodeFolderPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
```

Here `env.ContentRootPath` contains this value:

```
C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\Abc.Integration.OpticalType_App198\work
```

However because the `appsettings.json` files are located in:
`C:\SfDevCluster\Data\_App\_Node_0\Abc.Integration.OpticalType_App198\Abc.Integration.Optical.ServicePkg.Code.1.0.0`,

I'm forced to construct the `packageCodeFolderPath` variable you can see above.

This doesn't seem like a very elegant solution, and I'm worried the version number in `Pkg.Code.1.0.0` might change (if that is even a version number?).

How can I set `env.ContentRootPath` to be the path to the folder containing the `appsettings.json` files? Or is there a better way to go about accessing these files?

Comment: if `env.ContentRootPath` was pointing to the right directory, why you did have to do a `Path.Combine()` from the parent folder? Why not just use `config.SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)`

Comment: @DiegoMendes env.ContentRootPath is not pointing to the folder I want it to point to, which is the one with the json files. That's why I had to use Path.Combine() etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service manifest, you should set the `WorkingFolder` to `CodePackage` to have the ContentRootPath set to the code `Abc.Integration.Optical.ServicePkg.Code.1.0.0` instead of `work`.

i.e:

```
<EntryPoint>
  <ExeHost>
    <Program>myapp.exe</Program>
    <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
  </ExeHost>
</EntryPoint>
```

Check the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-existing-app#use-visual-studio-to-package-and-deploy-an-existing-executable)

Other option is get the information from the environment variables set by SF. Take a look in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-environment-variables-reference

Or, use the `context.CodePackageActivationContext.WorkDirectory` as suggested by Loek in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the `serviceContext` property `CodePackageActivationContext` to locate the SF [work folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.codepackageactivationcontext.workdirectory?view=azure-dotnet) and use that as your point of reference. (The value of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` varies on 1 node vs 5 node cluster, so it's unreliable.)

So use:
`context.CodePackageActivationContext.WorkDirectory`

The `CodePackageActivationContext` also holds the code package [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.codepackageactivationcontext.codepackageversion?view=azure-dotnet) string (which is indeed a version definition).

Comment: How do I access serviceContext in my stateless service? I don't have that variable in my code. I have this method as well:
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return this.CreateServiceRemotingInstanceListeners();
        }

Comment: It's the argument passed to the service constructor and the `serviceContext` passed to the communication listener, or the `Service.Context` property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.runtime.statelessservice.context?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I had a look at Context.CodePackageActivationContext.WorkDirectory from within my Service class but it's the same value as env.ContentRootPath