# How do you access the StatelessServiceContext instance from outside the ServiceInstanceListener constructor

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.2

I have the following code in an Azure Service Fabric Web API project:

```
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
            {
                new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext => //rest ommitted for brevity
            }
        }
```

Is there a way I can access the `serviceContext` from outside the `ServiceInstanceListener` constructor?

I'm hoping there might be something like `StatelessServiceContext statelessServiceContext = StatelessServiceContext.GetCurrentContext();`

The reason I'm wanting to do this is to access the `StatelessServiceContext.CodePackageActivationContext` property in a method where I'm not using the `ServiceInstanceListener` constructor.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822261/how-does-ihostingenvironment-contentrootpath-get-set) for more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this.Context` inside the service.